# How to read query param value if special character (&) part of query param value

Tags: java, rest, https, urlencode

Url: `https://myproject.dev.com/methodology/Culture?contentName=abc & def&path=Test&type=folder`

Need to fetch only query params from above URL but problem is '&' in `contentName=abc & def` so while fetching the contentName getting the value in two parts like abc, def.

Please suggest the approach to get contentName is `abc & def` instead of abc,def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the & character is part of the name or value in the query string then it has to be percent encoded. In the given example: `contentName=abc%26def&path=Test&type=folder`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.If contentName=abc & def (included spaces)then encode abc%20%26%20def so this case it is not working as excepted

Comment: As per the specification the space should get encoded as '+'.  As @Trisav pointed out you can use `URLEncoder (wrongly named :-))` class.

Answer (score 1):

If we pass any type of special character we have to encode those values. Java provides a `URLEncoder` class for encoding any query string or form parameter into URL encoded format. When encoding URI, one of the common pitfalls is encoding the complete URI. Typically, we need to encode only the query portion of the URI.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> requestParameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    requestParameters.put("contentName", "abc & def");
    requestParameters.put("path", "Test");
    requestParameters.put("type", "folder");

    String encodedURL = requestParameters.keySet().stream()
            .map(key -> key + "=" + encodeValue(requestParameters.get(key)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&", "https://myproject.dev.com/methodology/Culture?", ""));
    System.out.println(encodedURL);
}

private static String encodeValue(String value) {
    String url = "";
    try {
        url = URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Output:

```
https://myproject.dev.com/methodology/Culture?contentName=abc+%26+def&path=Test&type=folder
```